# jqueryUI resizable and draggable doesn't work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a problem when I use `jquery-ui resizable` and `draggable` together. Below mentioned is the scenario when the problem occurs:

**first move parent Div ,

then resize child Div.

finally child Div display incorrectly**

if I remove the resizable's  `containment` option the effort will be ok.

I find the option `containment and`helper` can't both coexist.

thank you

Here is the demo

```js
// external js: draggabilly.pkgd.js

$('.father').draggable({
  handle:'.p1'
}).resizable({
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
      containment: "parent" 
    });
$('.child').draggable({
  handle:'.p2'
}).resizable({
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
      containment: "parent" 
    });
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.draggable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #F90;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.draggable.is-pointer-down {
  background: #09F;
}
p{ background: #F00;}
.child {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.draggable.is-dragging { opacity: 0.7; }
.ui-resizable-helper{ border: 1px dotted #20a0ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="draggable ui-widget-content father ">
  <p class ="p1">handle</p>
  <div id="resizable" class="draggable ui-widget-content child">
    <p class ="p2">handle</p>
    1234345 6
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: i use other draggable library ,the jqUI resizable also can't work correctly, so i think the jqUI resizable has a bug. can you help me .

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from using helpers, I've found many issues using them.

When using jquery-ui interactions I use an inner element in the container so that the widgets are not affected by any other elements in the container. For example, your resize containment was not working correctly because of the "p1" element, to avoid this you could either do what I have done by adding an inner element, or make any other inner elements `position: absolute;` so that they do not affect the ui-element.

Here is my example:

```js
$('.father').draggable({
  handle: '.p1'
}).resizable({});

var containTo = $('.father-inner');
$('.child').draggable({
  handle: '.p2',
  containment: containTo
}).resizable({
  containment: containTo
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.father-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.draggable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.draggable.is-pointer-down {
  background: #09F;
}

p {
  background: #F00;
}

.child {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.draggable.is-dragging {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.ui-resizable-helper {
  border: 1px dotted #20a0ff;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: se-resize;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content father ">
  <p class="p1">handle</p>
  <div class="father-inner">
    <div id="resizable" class="draggable ui-widget-content child">
      <p class="p2">handle</p>
      1234345 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```